# Android market legacy copy protection

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application on the Android Market that was published over a year ago using the market legacy copy protection (which is still active but depreciated over the new licensing model).  I have read many accounts that if I turn off the legacy copy protection, current customers will no longer be able to access the application.  Since the legacy copy protection was officially depreciated, sales of my application have decreased dramatically, is it possible that because legacy copy protection is on, that newer devices no longer "see" my application?  More importently, how do I turn off legacy copy protection w/o alienating existing customers?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK if you turn off copy protection, users won't be able to classically update your application when a new version is available. They will need to un-install first and then re-install the version with copy protection turned off.
I don't think copy protection ON hides your app from the market (but maybe it will one day).